# Which should be 'give me' or 'pay me'?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Which of these two is the correct form to say?

> I would sell my book if you *give me* 100 dollars

or

> I would sell my book if you *pay me* 100 dollars

Are there alternatives to say the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these sentences are acceptable, with the latter being more natural. This is because you directly can associate '***pay***' with '***sell***' or '***buy***'.

Additionally, you can even say:

> *I would sell my book to you for 100 dollars*

Comment: Which of these 3 is more formal to say?

Comment: @Isa, '_give_' is mostly informal. So I would suggest using '_pay_' in a formal context. But that's just my opinion.